# Physical Fitness Self-Evaluation: Let's Get Critical!

Tags: discussion, quality-evaluation

You love your site and we love your site, but there is a whole world of people out there who might not even know it exists. When they do find it, their first impression will either scare them away or keep them around. Given this, let's take a hard look at the questions and answers here and make sure newcomers see the site at its best!

Below you'll find ten questions randomly selected from this site. What do you think about each of them and their answers? Are they the best they can be or can they be improved? Would they look interesting and inviting to an outsider or are they a little embarrassing?

Upvote the corresponding post here on meta when we're awesome. Downvote when our content just isn't quite up to par.

Oh, and do comment to let everyone know your thoughts and take part in this conversation. :)

**[EDIT]:** As promised, here's some feedback from the team, aggregated a bit:

> Your site seems to be doing well! What needs to be closed is being closed, what needs to be handled is being handled. I for one would love to see more editing and more room for involvement from lower-rep users. Maybe pointing some of them to the new /review queues might help.
>
> In general, you've hitting your stride and growing nicely. We're happy with your progress thus far.

Somewhat short, but a core message of, "Stay the course," is always good. It means you're all doing the right things. I hope this is helpful!

Comment: This seems like an encouraging sampling to me. Some are very good, and some are ok... but none are embarrassing.

Comment: I'm in agreement with @Greg on his statement. It's a good batch, some are okay, but there are none that I immediately dislike.

Comment: Just for info. I checked the questions, but since I'm on my phone and vacation I haven't left any comments on individual questions

Comment: I agree, these questions range from OK to GREAT. It's reassuring to see nothing that immediately triggers my delete finger. :)

Comment: how are the questions selected?

Comment: @FredrikD They are randomly selected.

Comment: Thanks for all your help everyone! I'll be sure to get you some feedback as soon as I can :)

Comment: @MattChan et al -- check out new feedback!

Comment: @Aarthi - Thanks for the feedback, good to know we're doing good! :)

Answer (score 8):

[Does exercise REALLY increase the basal metabolism rate for any significant length of time after the exercise is over?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/7493/does-exercise-really-increase-the-basal-metabolism-rate-for-any-significant-leng)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: Great accepted answer on this one.

Answer (score 8):

[Best warm up for running](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/7390/best-warm-up-for-running)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: The disagreement, back-and-forth, and counter-answers on this one produced some GREAT info.

Answer (score 7):

[Squat racks and barbells on first floor of home gym: bad idea?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/7472/squat-racks-and-barbells-on-first-floor-of-home-gym-bad-idea)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: Not strictly a "fitness" question, but fits well with the site IMHO.

Answer (score 5):

[Should I exercise when my muscles are aching?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/7443/should-i-exercise-when-my-muscles-are-aching)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: One good answer, but more would make this question better.

Answer (score 4):

[Are Box Squats more like dead lifts or standard squats?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/7465/are-box-squats-more-like-dead-lifts-or-standard-squats)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Answer (score 3):

[Is increasing lung capacity a misnomer?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/7435/is-increasing-lung-capacity-a-misnomer)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: Another with one good answer, but more perspectives would be better...

Answer (score 3):

[Can I lose fat but stay the same weight?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/7439/can-i-lose-fat-but-stay-the-same-weight)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: Fair question. I'm glad that the OP came back with an edit. I'd like to see more than 1 answer.

Answer (score 3):

[What changes between the 5 rep range and the 10 rep range?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/7427/what-changes-between-the-5-rep-range-and-the-10-rep-range)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: Good question, needs more expert answers.

Answer (score 2):

[best way to cheat - cheat day? cheat meal?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/7396/best-way-to-cheat-cheat-day-cheat-meal)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: Veers a bit too much towards "nutrition" for my taste, but it's not as bad as some of the stuff I've seen.

Comment: It doesn't interest me, but it's a fair question about how to properly eat for leaning out.

Answer (score 0):

[How to reduce weight after quitting smoking](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/7498/how-to-reduce-weight-after-quitting-smoking)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: Too general. I don't see a substantial difference between losing weight generally and losing weight after quitting an addiction. It's not *awful* though.

Comment: Ditto. A little too general, but it's okay for me.